# how to write the last line of file

Tags: c#

I have a file data.txt. data.txt contains text line by line as:

one
two
three
six

Here I need to write data in file as:

one
two
three
**four**
**five**
six

I dont know how to write file like this!!

Comment: Accept previous answers, so people will want to help you.

Comment: Also, is this in C# or IronPython?

Comment: Will the data you write to the text file is same as you given or any changes

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to re-write the file when inserting - because text files have variable length rows.

There are optimizations you could employ: like extending a file and buffering and writing, but you may have to buffer an arbitrary amount - i.e. inserting a row at the top.

If we knew more about your complete scenario, we would be more able to help usefully.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your text file and put lines as array. Modify the array and save it back to file. But it's not a good idea if you have some other text file, for this particular example it can work no problem.